airflow-webserver , triggerer pods in pending state
I am trying to deploy airflow using helm on k8 cluster following the official document(helm). But the pods are either in pending state or initiating. I did create persistencevolume and persistentvolumeclaim.
what is the exact problem and the solution to it.
Having 1master(4CPU, 8RAM, 30gb memory) and 2worker node(redhat) with same configuration. I have setup k8 cluster and I want to deploy airflow on worker node. I tried with official document and many blogs but couln't resolve this...
NAMESPACE              NAME                                                                  READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS         AGE
airflow                airflow-postgresql-0                                                  0/1     Pending                 0                121m
airflow                airflow-redis-0                                                       0/1     Pending                 0                121m
airflow                airflow-scheduler-7fbb64bf55-pp246                                    0/2     Init:Error              17 (7m34s ago)   105m
airflow                airflow-statsd-6df8564664-tg6x5                                       1/1     Running                 0                105m
airflow                airflow-triggerer-0                                                   0/2     Pending                 0                121m
airflow                airflow-webserver-688d449fc6-nnphv                                    0/1     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   17 (29s ago)     105m
airflow                airflow-worker-0                                                      0/2     Pending                 0                121m
default                airflow-scheduler-6c8b9b97c-l2n4v                                     0/1     Pending                 0                143m
default                airflow-webserver-754bdb59f8-nr6xp                                    0/1     Pending                 0                143m

Can you please get the error message from the kubectl describe pod command output
